# integral problem multiple angles of sine/cosine

Tags: integration, complex-numbers

I am trying to integrate $\sin^6(x)\cos^4(x)$. I know that this can be converted into multiple angles to make the integral simpler-is there a strategy to finding the multiple angle equivalent? Could it be done using De Moivre's theorem?

Comment: You can use $\sin 2x = 2\sin x \cos x$ and $\cos 2x=1-2\sin^2 x$ with some care to reduce this to terms involving $\sin nx, \cos nx$ instead of powers. This is an unsystematic way of following Lord Shark's suggestion below. The reduction formulae suggested achieve essentially the same thing, and again are more systematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the reduction formula 
$$\int \sin^m x \cos^n x dx = \frac{\sin^{m+1}x \cos^{n-1} x}{m+n}+\frac{n-1}{m+n}\int \sin^m x \cos^{n-2} x dx$$
You will have to apply this multiple times before you whittle it down to $\sin^6 x$.
Then you can use the reduction formula
$$\int \sin^n x dx=-\frac{1}{n}\sin^{n-1}x \cos x +\frac{n-1}{n}\int \sin^{n-2} x dx$$
Whether you do it my way or "Lord Shark's" way, the final result is going to be a mess. This is not a very nice problem.

Comment: I am explicitly told to consider multiple angles

Comment: Oh. In that case, you could change it to $\frac{1}{2}\sin^4 2x \sin^2 x$, if that helps.

Comment: @gamma1 There are at least two answers now using multiple angles.

Answer (score 1):

Write is as
$$\frac{(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})^6(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})^4}{2^{10}i^6}$$
and expand out...

Comment: with a binomial expansion?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of "power reduction identities to know"

$\int \sin^n x\cos^m x dx$

If $m$ or $n$  is odd.  Then use the identities $\sin^2 x = 1-\cos^2 x$ and $\cos^2 x = 1-sin^2 x$ as needed until you have $\sin x$ or $\cos x$ not raised to any power and some string of the other function raised to a variety of powers.

then perform a $u$ substitution and turn it all into a polynomial.

If $m$ and $n$  are both even, use $\sin^2 x = \frac 12 (1-\cos 2x)$ and $\cos^2 x = \frac 12(1+\cos 2x)$ to reduce the power.  If $m$ or $n$ are now odd, use the techniqe described in the previous section.  If they are both still even, repeat.

Eventually you will reduce the powers of one of the factors to 1, were you can then do your u-sub.

$\int \sin^6 x\cos^4 x\ dx\\
\int (\frac 12 (1-\cos 2x))^3 (\frac 12(1+\cos 2x)^2\ dx\\
(\frac 12)^5 \int (1-\cos 2x)(1-\cos 2x)^2(1+\cos 2x)^2\ dx\\
(\frac 12)^5 \int (1+\cos 2x)(1-\cos^2 2x)^2\  dx\\
(\frac 12)^5 \int (\sin^4 2x) (1+\cos 2x)\ dx\\
(\frac 12)^5 [\int (\sin^4 2x)\  dx +  \int (\sin^4 2x\cos 2x)\ dx$

The integral on the right we can tackle with a u substitution.

$\int (\sin^4 2x)\  dx\\
(\frac 12)^4 \int (1-\cos 4x)^2\   dx\\
(\frac 12)^4 \int 1-2\cos 4x + \cos^2 4x\   dx\\
(\frac 12)^4 \int 1-2\cos 4x + \frac 12 (1-\cos 8x)\   dx$

And that you can integrate.

And then you will need to put the pieces together.

Answer (score 0):

Integration by parts (as shown in another answer) seems almost to be the "standard" approach (at least judging from my recollection of the tables of integrals).

Alternatively, write $\sin^6 x \cos^4 x = (\sin^2 x)(\sin x \cos x)^4.$
Then use the identities
$\sin^2 x = \frac12(1 - \cos (2x))$ and $\sin x \cos x = \frac12 \sin(2x).$
Therefore
$$
\sin^6 x \cos^4 x = \frac{1}{32} (1-\cos(2x))\sin^4(2x).
$$
You can integrate $\cos(2x)\sin^4(2x)$ easily via the substitution 
$u = \sin(2x).$

Integrating $\sin^4(2x)$ takes a little more work,
for example 
\begin{align}
\sin^4(2x) &= (1 - cos^2(2x))\sin^2(2x) = \sin^2(2x) - \sin^2(2x)\cos^2(2x)\\
&= \frac12(1 - \cos (4x)) - \frac14  \sin^2(4x)\\
&= \frac12(1 - \cos (4x)) - \frac18 (1 - \cos (8x))\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Note that 
$$
\cos^4 (x) = (1 - \sin^2(x))^2,
$$
then you have
$$
\int (\sin^{10}(x) - 2\sin^8(x) + \sin^6(x))dx.
$$
You can break this up into the sum of 3 integrals involving powers of sine. You can solve each of these using the formula
$$
\int \sin^{n}(x) = \frac{n-1}{n}\int \sin^{n-2}(x)dx - \frac{\cos(x) \sin^{n-1}(x)}{n}.
$$
Alternatively, you can reduce the power of each of these sine functions using multiple angles by using the formula
$$
\sin^2 (x) = \frac{1 - \cos(2x)}{2}.
$$
Using multiple angles is more tedious in my opinion.